# Is there any way to save snippets in CMD

Tags: cmd

Is there any way so save snippets in CMD(win7). I mean, I type: command01 + trigger and it converts to something like: git config --global core.editor "vim". Or if there is some 3th party program or scripts that does that.

Comment: The `vim` tag is useless, here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### aliases

For full aliases of complex commands, just write one-line batch files:

E.g. `git-set-vim.cmd`:

```
@git config --global core.editor "vim"
```

These would correspond to Bash functions or aliases.

#### snippets

For snippets (i.e. parts of a command where you still need to do additional editing beyond appending command arguments), you indeed need a third-party extension.

I'd recommend [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), which allows you to define macros trigger by key combinations (and other system automation), also depending on the currently active type of program.

Answer (score 1):

The free `Autohotkey` allows you to repeat strings and paragraphs of text very easily.

`Autohotkey` is a tool that uses a config text file and it can include lines like this:

```
::.c::[code]echo Here is my code[/code]

::.b::[b]This is Bold[/b]

::address1::
send Peter PumpkinEater{enter}
send 213 The Patch{enter}
send Fairyland{enter}
return
```

and when you type `.c` and space then it will print `[code]echo Here is my code[/code]` to the `text editor` or `website forum` or `program` you are using at the time.

When you type `.b` and space it will print `[b]This is Bold[/b]`
and when you type `address1` and space it will type this:

Peter PumpkinEater
213 The Patch
Fairyland

It is far more powerful than just the `hotstrings` that I have outlined and is a wonderful tool.